# Open .unity3d file on Android

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine

I've a unity3d file and I've created a simply desktop unity player who I pass the unity3d path as argument to run the animation.

I'd like to do the same on Android native app. There is a way to pass the path to an unity player? Which classes I've to create/extend?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer();
mUnityPlayer.start(xxx.unity3d);
```